# Hide or Delete duplicate cells of row while displaying all records in jsp?

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp, duplicates

I want to fetch all records from PostgreSQL db. But there will be one column in which duplicate values can occur.

So, I want to display all records while displaying only one record from the duplicate ones.

[image]

I want the 1st picture to be like 2nd one.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the `resultset` from the database query, you can use a java Set to control, whether or not you have added a id previously.

Something like this (*I guess your id's are Strings*):

```
Set<String> addedIds = new HashSet<String>();

//get your db resultset and do loop

if(addedIds.contains(requestId)){
    //Do not print this requestId in html table
} else {
    //Print the id in html table
    addedIds.add(requestId);
}
```

Of course this solution works if you have your data ordered by `requestId`, so if this is not the case, please order it before.

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough  for your use case (provided, of course, that your data are sorted)

```
    String currentRequestId = null;
    while(resultSet.next()){
    String requestId = resultSet.getString(1);
    int serialNo = resultSet.getInt(2);
    String applName= resultSet.getString(3);

    out.print("<tr>");

    if(!requestId.equals(currentRequestId))//print requestId only if different
        out.print("<td>"+ requestId+ "</td>");
    else
        out.print("<td></td>");//print empty cell

    out.print("<td>"+ serialNo+ "</td>");
    out.print("<td>"+ applName+ "</td>");
    out.print("<tr>");

    currentRequestId = requestId;

}
```

Note, however, that using Java in a jsp is really bad and should be avoided.